# Is there a Kafka counterpart to AWS Kinesis Firehose?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Looks like AWS Kinesis Firehose is a way to ingest data (buffered together) to an object, is there a Kafka counterpart for this kind of functionality?

Comment: This was supposed to be done by Apache Flume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/design.html), which is part of Apache Kafka.

You can use it with a [variety of connectors](https://www.confluent.io/hub/), for streaming data in from a source (RDBMS, JMS, MQTT, CSV, etc etc) to a Kafka topic, and from a Kafka topic to a target (RDBMS, S3, BigQuery, HDFS, etc etc)

Kafka Connect in action:

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/blogthe-simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-in-the-world-or-thereabouts-part-2/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent.*

Comment: Is it possible to connect data from Kinesis Firehose (or its S3 products) to Kafka ?